# Custom Stylesheet not overriding Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've tried putting my CSS file link below the Bootstrap CDN link (as it is now) to being as specific as I can (even putting `background: #ffcc00;` instead of `background-color: #ffcc00;`, because I read somewhere that was supposed to work!)

```css
.active {
    background-color: #FF8040;
    color: white;
}

.navbar #myNavbar {
    background: #ffcc00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Play Games 3.0</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="topgames.html">Top Games</a></li>
          <li><a href="gamelist.html">Game List</a></li>
          <li><a href="vote.html">Vote For Games</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
    <h1>Welcome to Play Games 3.0!</h1>
    <p>You can use the navigation bar above or choose your favorite game from the categories below!</p>
</body>
```

**Screenshot of Fiddle not working**:

[image: SS]

P.S: Could it possibly be due to me using a CDN instead of hosting it myself? That's my only guess so far.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66xnysd1/)

Comment: Have you tried using the browser inspector to see what rules are being overridden?

Comment: show us your header or provide a link..

Comment: Try adding "!important". That often does it for me when I'm using bootstrap and have similar issues.

Comment: Provide jsfiddle maybe?

Comment: !important should be highly discouraged since it's so dangerous. You should just give us a link of a snippet first,

Comment: @James Not a good idea, especially when you don't know what the OPs problem is.

Comment: @JacobGray I checked with the browser inspector and I can't see any problems.

Comment: @DaveG linked to jsfiddle

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAOt92fAsGlPdJk0koe1hOB9o8Px2uK8u0Q — looks like it is working.

Comment: *`<p>it said I had to have some code so here ya go!<p>`* — The point is that the code you are asking about should be **in the question** and not hosted on some link that might break in the future.

Comment: Ok ok ok dude I'll fix it lol ;)

Comment: @Quentin why is it checkered like that???

Comment: What dude no it doesn't??!! I posted a screenshot of it not working for me also.

Comment: @dippas Okay...... why is only three of the drop downs colored, and the big bar not colored???? Also with a bigger screen nothing is colored...check the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is only three of the drop downs colored, and the big bar not
>   colored????

you are selecting the wrong selector, instead of selection `#myNavBar` you want to select/target the `.navbar-header`

```css
.active {
  background-color: #FF8040;
  color: white;
}
.navbar-header {
  background: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Play Games 3.0</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="topgames.html">Top Games</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="gamelist.html">Game List</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="vote.html">Vote For Games</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<h1>Welcome to Play Games 3.0!</h1>
<p>You can use the navigation bar above or choose your favorite game from the categories below!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three factors which affect the overriding of styles in CSS.

#### The first is order of definition, i.e.

```
<style>
  h1 { font-size:18pt; }
</style>

<style>
  h1 { font-size:100pt; }
</style>
```

The second h1 definition, having come after the first is applied instead of the first.

#### The second is order included in the element.

```
<style>
  h1.smaller { font-size:18pt; }
  h1.bigger { font-size:100pt; }
</style>
...
<div class="smaller bigger"></div>
<div class="bigger smaller"></div>
```

The first style included in the class definition is overriden by the second...

#### The third is narrowness of scope

```
<style>
  div.effect { padding:5px; background: #000; }
  div > div > div.effect { padding:20px; background:#FFF; }
</style>

<div class="effect"></div>
<div><div><div class="effect"></div></div></div>
```

The first `div.effect` would have the general effect applied with a small padding and black background.

The second `div.effect` would have the specialized effect applied to it.

Depending on your goals, you may need to create classes with more specific scope.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only problem I have with it is **I'm using the first and third of those,** and I'm not sure how exactly the second applies (to my question, anyway....)...if you could explain that to me, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: I had responded before you posted the fiddle.  Basically if you don't see any reaction to the style, you are either not specific enough in your declaration or you aren't targeting the element you think you are.